# Can't Flash Code to Particle Photon

Tags: arduino, firmware, usb-flash-drive, particle.io, particle-photon

I have a Particle Photon which I'm trying to setup. I've tried flashing code both from the web IDE, and locally and it always times out. The device is connecting as it can be seen in these pictures:
[image: Seen in the web IDE]

The web IDE does not give me much information. It only says "Request Timed Out". This is what I get when I try to flash an .ino code

```
MacBook-Pro:Desktop User$ particle flash ABCDEFGH123456789 sketch_jun09a/
Including:
    sketch_jun09a/sketch_jun09a.ino
attempting to flash firmware to your device ABCDEFGH123456789
Flash device failed.
Request Timed Out
```

And when I try to flash a firmware.bin file this is what I get:

```
MacBook-Pro:Downloads Usesr$ particle flash --usb firmware.bin 
Found DFU device 2b04:d006
spawning dfu-util -d 2b04:d006 -a 0 -i 0 -s 0x080A0000:leave -D firmware.bin
dfu-util 0.9

Copyright 2005-2009 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc.
Copyright 2010-2016 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt
This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Please report bugs to http://sourceforge.net/p/dfu-util/tickets/

dfu-util: Invalid DFU suffix signature
dfu-util: A valid DFU suffix will be required in a future dfu-util release!!!
Opening DFU capable USB device...
ID 2b04:d006
Run-time device DFU version 011a
Claiming USB DFU Interface...
Setting Alternate Setting #0 ...
Determining device status: state = dfuIDLE, status = 0
dfuIDLE, continuing
DFU mode device DFU version 011a
Device returned transfer size 4096
DfuSe interface name: "Internal Flash   "
Downloading to address = 0x080a0000, size = 5224
Download    [=========================] 100%         5224 bytes
Download done.
File downloaded successfully
dfu-util: Error during download get_status

Error writing firmware...dfu-util: Invalid DFU suffix signature
dfu-util: A valid DFU suffix will be required in a future dfu-util release!!!

dfu-util: Error during download get_status
```

I've seen online that the firmware.bin file seems to be compiled for the Particle Core, and not the Photon, so the device does not allow the code to be flashed. How should I compile the code for it to work? Is there any other solution to this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to flash a Core firmware to a Photon (they have different architecture and firmware layout). To compile the code for photon you can also use the CLI:

```
$ particle compile photon sketch_jun09a/
```

the resulting binary can be flashed using the CLI the same way you did.

To figure out the failed over the air flash I would recommend [contacting the support](https://docs.particle.io/support/support-and-fulfillment/menu-base/#form-main).